# Can't open Android SDK Manager

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to open the SDK Manager using Eclipse but the following error appears:

```
[2013-12-16 23:21:25 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display
[2013-12-16 23:21:25 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:346)
[2013-12-16 23:21:25 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:320)
[2013-12-16 23:21:25 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:120)
[2013-12-16 23:21:25 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:103)
[2013-12-16 23:21:25 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
[2013-12-16 23:21:25 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
[2013-12-16 23:21:25 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
[2013-12-16 23:21:25 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[2013-12-16 23:21:25 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
[2013-12-16 23:21:25 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[2013-12-16 23:21:25 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[2013-12-16 23:21:25 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[2013-12-16 23:21:25 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   ... 4 more
```

I have tried almost everything:

- Fixing the Environment Path
- Reinstalling Java
- Reinstalling Android SDK
- Edit android.bat
- Edit Java paths in Eclipse

And so on..

What is really strange, is that today I've ran Eclipse in another computer almost the same as mine and, like magic, it worked perfectly, I opened SDK Manager without errors.

I didn't figured out what's the difference. Both computers uses Windows 7 Pro 64bits. Java paths are the same as well.

So, can anyone help me? =/

Comment: you didn't mention whether you had reinstalled Eclipse. If not, download the latest one, and have a try.

Comment: Oh sorry, I installed Eclipse with Android SDK. I downloaded it in the Google Developer website. But I don't think that Eclipse or SDK is the problem, as it run without problem in the other computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed it!
Just entered in the **Enviroment Variables** and deleted the followings:

- ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK
- ANDROID_SWT
- JAVA_HOME
- JDK_HOME
- PATH

I can't explain why it worked, but it doesn't matter now! :P

Comment: I don't understand how and why it works, but this answer really helpful!

Comment: i had problems starting it because ANDROID_SWT was pointing to the wrong location. this answer actually helped :) thanks